# Constructing a query string using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, strings, url, null

I speedily wrote a bunch of crappy checks, to check whether strings are empty, in order to build a query string.

```
StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();

SB.AppendFormat("{0}guide/search.aspx?", root);
```

`root` is a `const`, containing the website address.
It's like this because we have test servers.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) {
    SB.AppendFormat("&i={0}", Server.UrlEncode(item));
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(found)) {
      SB.AppendFormat("&f={0}", Server.UrlEncode(found));
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(what)) {
      SB.AppendFormat("&wt={0}", Server.UrlEncode(what));
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(where)) {
      SB.AppendFormat("&wr={0}", Server.UrlEncode(where));
}
```

I tried replacing these with ternaries, but I couldn't get my head around how to do that with the `sb.AppendFormat` in place.

- Is there a better way to check empty strings than -`String.IsNullOrEmpty`?
- Is my method of naming variables correct with C# standards?
- Is `Server.UrlEncode` the best way to format strings into query strings?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Although there's nothing wrong with your code, it is generally easier to fall back on framework classes for this kind of thing. Namely `UriBuilder` and `HttpValueCollection`.

```
public static Uri BuildUri(string root, NameValueCollection query)
{
    // omitted argument checking

    // sneaky way to get a HttpValueCollection (which is internal)
    var collection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

    foreach (var key in query.Cast<string>().Where(key => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(query[key])))
    {
       collection[key] = query[key];
    }

    var builder = new UriBuilder(root) { Query = collection.ToString() };
    return builder.Uri;
}
```

Then you can simply use with a name value collection:

```
var values = new NameValueCollection 
{ 
    {"i", "item" }, 
    { "f", "found" },
    { "wt", "what%" },
    { "wr", "where" }
}; 
BuildUri("http://example.com/search.aspx", values);
// http://example.com/search.aspx?i=item&f=found&wt=what%25&wr=where
```

The `HttpValueCollection` handles all of the encoding for you so you don't need to worry about doing it the right way. You just create the name value collection and any null/empty values will just be skipped in the `BuildUri` method.

**Update**

As svick has pointed out in the comments it might not be ideal to use an internal class in this way. I think the risk of the implementation changing is quite low but it is a risk and should be thought about.

Comment: Didn't know this, good to know.

Comment: @Quill to show the value being url encoded.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to fall back internal framework classes and rely on their undocumented behavior.

Comment: @svick - that's certainly a valid concern. I think the risk in `HttpValueCollection` changing is very low but you are right: it could lead to a pretty subtle bug if it ever did change.

Answer (score 8):

how about:

```
QueryBuilder.For("guide/search.aspx")
    .Query("i", item)
    .Query("f", found)
    .Query("wt", what)
    .Query("wr", where)
    .ToString();

public class QueryBuilder
{
    public static QueryBuilder For(string page)
    {
        return new QueryBuilder(page);
    }

    private readonly StringBuilder sb;

    private QueryBuilder(string page)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder()
                 .AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               "{0}{1}?",
                               root,
                               page);
    }

    public QueryBuilder Query(string queryName, string queryValue)
    {
        // todo: throw if parameter sb or queryValue is null

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryValue))
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvarianteCulture,
                            "&{0}={1}",
                            queryName,      
                            Server.UrlEncode(what));
        }

        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

regarding your questions:

- `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is ok. Depending on the use case `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` (=> null or empty or only whitespaces like space, tab, newline) may be a good fit too.
- local variable names should be lower case `StringBuilder sb` instead of `StringBuilder SB`

Comment: An extension method is a little bit overkill for this use, I would agree to create a separate method but its purpose is, in my opinion, too small to create an extension method. From MSDN on the guidelines for extension methods: `In general, we recommend that you implement extension methods sparingly and only when you have to.`.

Comment: Agreed. Possibly a subclass (or wrapper) for `StringBuilder` that encapsulates this behaviour would make sense. `QueryBuilder` perhaps?

Comment: @Abbas I Agree that a Wrapper would be a better solution. I wouldn't subclass, because a) a lot of the `StringBuilder`s methods are not needed and b) one should favor composition over inheritance

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, i refactored the code to a separate class.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Yes, good point. A `QueryBuilder` that offered an `AppendLine` method would not make much sense.

Comment: FWIW I recently implemented a query builder that looked a lot like this, only I utilized the `UriBuilder` internally. It ended up looking something like `var uri = new ReportUriBuilder("hostname", "path").AddQuery("paramName",42).Uri`

Answer (score 5):

What you have is a collection of key-value pairs of strings, and you're performing the same operation on all of them. A simple improvement is to throw them into a collection and iterate over it.

```
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("i", item), // "item"
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("f", found), // null or ""
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("wt", what), // "what"
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("wr", where) // "where"
};

foreach (string parameter in parameters)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter)) {
        SB.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", parameter.Key, Server.UrlEncode(parameter.Value));
    }
}
// http://example.com/guide/search.aspx?&i=item&wt=what&wh=where
```

There is a problem with your code and the code above, though: the query string is always going to start with an ampersand. A quick and dirty solution would be to build out the query string first, and then take a substring to truncate the first character before appending it to the StringBuilder.

Another way to solve this is using Linq to filter and format the data, and then bringing it all together with a `String.Join` call, in which we can specify the ampersand as a separator.

```
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("i", item), // "item"
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("f", found), // null or ""
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("wt", what), // "what"
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("wr", where) // "where"
};

var validParameters = parameters.Where(p => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Value));
var formattedParameters = validParameters.Select(p => p.Key + "=" + Server.UrlEncode(p.Value));
SB.Append(String.Join("&", formattedParameters));
// http://example.com/guide/search.aspx?i=item&wt=what&wh=where
```